# runas or psexec inside Windows container

Tags: docker, docker-for-windows, psexec, runas, windows-server-2019

I have a windows image based on `mcr.microsoft.com/windows:1809`.

In my Dockerfile, I created a new user via

`net user /add myuser mypassword`

Now I would like to enter the container, e.g. via `docker run -it` and execute commands via the `myuser` (instead of the standard user `ContainerAdministrator`).

I tried both `runas` and `psexec` but both commands did not work as expected or gave various errors, among others [these](https://superuser.com/q/1185595/422184) and [these](https://serverfault.com/q/357549/333212).

How can I run a command inside a Windows docker container as a different user other than `ContainerAdministrator`?

Answer (score 1):

Use the **--user** arg while running "docker run" command. In your case your user "myuser" will be the arg value as below

**docker run -it --user "myuser" <image_id>  cmd**